# Batch echo|set /p only write " in txt document

Tags: batch-file

I nedd Help please !

I have to write a inline string to a txt document.

One part of the string is a simple " i have tryed many ways but dont figure out the right.

I have only to write " in a line withe the text before and the text after.

Here some that i have tryed:

```
echo ^" >> test.txt // work but with line break

echo|set /p = ^" >> test.txt //Dont work
echo|set /p = "^"" >> test.txt // Dont work
```

etc...

Hope someone can help me.

Thak you !

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to resort the syntax. Put the destination and source in front of the `set`:

```
>test.txt <nul set /p ="""
```

"Write to test.txt" - "get empty input (Enter)" - "write `"` (enclosed in doublequotes)"

A single `"` is interpreted as "start of...", therefore you have to enclose it in doublequotes.

Yes, I know - it's ugly...

Answer (score 1):

As Stephan said, a single quote is only handled as a starting quote here.

But I prefere the extended `set` syntax

```
>test.txt <nul set /p "dummyVar=""
```

The extended `set` syntax requires a quote just before the variable name and one quote at the end.
Both quotes will not be a part of the content, but at the last quote the content will stop.

```
<nul set /p "var=hello & you"  this is not visible
```

As you can see, Stephan and also in my samples we use `<nul` instead of `echo |`, as a pipe will start two new cmd.exe tasks and echo itself is slower than a normal redirect.